# Who on Earth tweeted this painfully mediocre question?

Tags: discussion, support, site-promotion

[Should you list a desired position title in your resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13970/437)

I just noticed that the above question [was tweeted by @StackWorkplace](https://mobile.twitter.com/StackWorkplace/status/371606836275068930); to which I have to say...

> *...Seriously?*

This question is probably on-topic but it's *painfully* mediocre, and it's not exactly the type of content that we want to promote on Workplace.Beta.SE.

Did a human tweet this question? Or did an automated algorithm tweet this question?

Either way, we really need to think about the type of content that we promote on Twitter. We certainly don't want the @StackWorkplace account to be tweeting noise.

Comment: The twitterbot is automated. I don't know enough about it at this point to actually write up an answer, though.

Comment: Do we have a mediocrity-level that must be exceeded for a question to be considered worthwhile?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Your question sounds rhetorical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [@StackWorkplace Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackWorkplace) is indeed run by an automated bot. No human runs this account. What's more, each Stack Exchange site has its own Twitter account that automatically tweets open, up voted questions. I assume the question was up voted at the time it was tweeted although now it has a score of zero.

According to [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183407/155826), the algorithm to determine when -- and if -- to tweet is based on how hot the question is based on views.

With that said, I'm not sure this question is really all that bad. It's not a difficult problem, and there's likely already answers out there on the Internet that answer this question, but it's definitely something that both applies to the workplace and can be answered with facts, references, and specific expertise.

It's good someone is keeping an eye on the feed though. If it were to tweet negatively-scored or closed questions, that would *definitely* be something that we would want to address.

Comment: There's some more info in my question & ChrisF's answer re: tweets leading to (some) closed questions on ProgSE that might be helpful/useful/something: [Should we be concerned that @StackProgrammer tweets lead to closed/deleted questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/should-we-be-concerned-that-stackprogrammer-tweets-lead-to-closed-deleted-quest)

Comment: @jcmeloni, Thing is, I'm not sure how much this really matters. A *person* -- someone more interesting than an automated bot -- with a good social media following on Twitter can make a far greater impact. What's more, the bot has only 73 followers, which is a pretty small group of people. We should be using the share links underneath each question and share with our own followers, which scales a lot more if all of us are doing that.

Comment: Sure, but the question is about the bot.

Comment: Right, got that part, @jcmeloni. Where I was going with this is do we really want to spend valuable time on something that yields little result for our site, or do we want to focus on areas that arguably could make a much larger impact? I don't see the Twitter bot as anything that should take up our time, unless it starts to spit out down-voted, closed questions, or questions about how to bake cakes. Hope this helps clarify. :)

Comment: I'll put this on my list of things to ask the Community Team, in the interests of being thorough. I'd be interested to see how much of our Twitter traffic comes from the bot vs us, the users.

Comment: I'm not following where there's anything in this question or my comment that is about anything that "takes our time". The SE bot does things. If we notice the bot doing strange things, based on the current accepted baseline, someone should note it to the Team. I don't think it's behaving programmatically inappropriately here.  My comment and link to ProgSE Meta was to show that there have been questions w/ answers about the bots elsewhere, that have information that help answer the question here: namely, that the bot is a bot, and it works a certain way per SE.

Comment: ...which some people may or may not find useful or interesting.